# Deterministic part of ARMA's Wold decomposition

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, deterministic

According to Wold's Theorem, any covariance-stationary process can be decomposed as the sum of a deterministic part and a purely non-deterministic part, where the latter one has some MA infinity representation. My question is: for an ARMA(p,q) model, can we treat the AR(p) part of the model as the deterministic component and MA(q) part as the purely non-deterministic part? Will this lead to a valid Wold representation?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The AR part consists of random variables, and these are not deterministic.